# how to pass argument to afxbeginthread

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, afx

I am running a modeless dialog box using afxbeginthread. I have created a new class derived from Cwinthread and Overridden the initinstance as below.

```
BOOL GuiThread::InitInstance(void)
{
    CWinThread::InitInstance();
    dialog *dial = new dialog;
    this->m_pMainWnd = dial;
    dial->Create(dialog::IDD);
    dial->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    return TRUE;
}
```

In my main thread, I am creating a user interface thread as follows.

```
GuiThread *gui = (GuiThread*)AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(GuiThread),THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,NULL,NULL);
WaitForSingleObject(gui->m_hThread,INFINITE);
```

My question is: How I can pass an argument to the GUI thread? I want to pass a string: How can I do that?

Comment: You can send user-defined message to `gui->m_pMainWnd` and handle it in the`dialog` class. Pass parameters through LPARAM and WPARAM.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CREATE_SUSPENDED flag to create the thread object without starting the thread, then set member variables of the thread object and start the thread:

```
GuiThread *gui = (GuiThread*)AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(GuiThread),THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL);
gui->m_sometext = sometext;
gui->ResumeThread();
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you. But what if i want to update m_sometext once the thread has started. Can i suspend my thread, update the variable and again resume the thread. Is it fine? Note:I am using this thread for running modeless dialog box.

Comment: No, that is not an adequate way to synchronize access to data between two threads. Both threads should sandwich access to the shared data between EnterCriticalSection and LeaveCriticalSection calls.  You could also take the approach suggested by Alex Farber.